# Match only roman numerals with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a reg exp to match only roman numerals, and remove them only when there are other characters before.
If there are not other characters before the roman numeral then I don't want to remove it.
Here is an example:

```
string1 V
string2 VI
string3 XX
STRING4 I
STRING5 1340 I
2 STRING6 III
STRING7 V
STRING8 III
STRING9 II
STRING10 IV
STRING11 STRING12 VI
STRING13! IX
STRING14 VI
. STRING15 - STRING16_ V
STRING17 1/2 VI
STRING18 VIII
XIII (2011)
V (2012)
String19 VP
XII
```

the result should be:

```
string1
string2
string3
STRING4
STRING5 1340
2 STRING6
STRING7
STRING8
STRING9
STRING10
STRING11 STRING12
STRING13!
STRING14
. STRING15 - STRING16_
STRING17 1/2
STRING18
XIII (2011)
V (2012)
String19 VP
XII
```

Any help please?

Thanks

**edit**: I have just tried this: `\b[IVXLCDM]+\b` but it matches:

```
XIII (2011)
V (2012)
XII
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Is there a whitespace in front of every roman you like to remove?

Comment: @mgutt yes there is always a whitespace before and after every roman numeral

Comment: Every or every you like to remove?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `[ ]\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b`

Includes only **valid** ROMAN NUMERALS.

If you want to include romans without validation you can use `[ ]([MDCLXVI]+$)`

see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iO2vQ6/1).

Comment: It is really difficult to check for valid romans.. so i thought i could make a point.. :D

Comment: you are right.. but php engine covers pcre regular expressions too.. thats why pcre(php) :)

Comment: gald that you think it is great answer.. :)

Comment: this clearly wont work case the roman numeral is the first thing in the string the string "IV" or "I something" wont be valid by this regex... very poor answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$subjects = <<< EOT
string1 V
string2 VI
string3 XX
STRING4 I
STRING5 1340 I
2 STRING6 III
STRING7 V
STRING8 III
STRING9 II
STRING10 IV
STRING11 STRING12 VI
STRING13! IX
STRING14 VI
. STRING15 - STRING16_ V
STRING17 1/2 VI
STRING18 VIII
XIII (2011)
V (2012)
String19 VP
XII
EOT;

foreach (explode("\n",$subjects) as $subject) {
  $pattern = '/(.+)\s+[IVXLCDM]+\s*$/';
  echo preg_replace($pattern, '\\1', $subject)."\n";
}
```

This gives the output:

```
string1
string2
string3
STRING4
STRING5 1340
2 STRING6
STRING7
STRING8
STRING9
STRING10
STRING11 STRING12
STRING13!
STRING14
. STRING15 - STRING16_
STRING17 1/2
STRING18
XIII (2011)
V (2012)
String19 VP
XII
```

Note: this also removes any white spaces between the preceding text and the removed roman number sequence. If you want to preserve those you have to move the `\n` into the brackets before: `'/(.+\s+)[CILMVX]+$/'`.

Comment: @karthikmanchala Thanks, removed the `P` from the pattern. Sorry, I am not fluent with roman numbers...